# Python Not Using Elif Statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a virtual coffee shop, in which the amount of an item a customer asks for would adjust the total for payment. However, when I run my code, and I enter more than 1 of an item, it simply skips the step that would inform the user of their total.

Code:

```
import time

print("Hello! Welcome to George's Coffee.")
name = input("What is your name for the order?\n")
print("\nHello " + name + "! Thank you for coming to George's Coffee!\n")
print("On todays menu, we have the following:\n" + "Lattee\n" + "Hot Chocolate\n" + "Mocha\n" + "Celcius\n" + "Cappuchino\n" + "Black Coffee\n" + "All items are $8 because we need money to fund the hacking of the government.")

price = 8
order = input("\nWhat would you like to order today?\n")
quantity = input("How many " + order + "s would you like?\n")

#singular (=1)
if quantity == "1":
  if order == "Lattee":
    latte_total = float(2.95) * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(latte_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  elif order == "Hot Chocolate":
    hot_chocolate_total = 2 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(hot_chocolate_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  elif order == "Mocha":
    mocha_total = 5 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(mocha_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  elif order == "Celcius":
    cel_total = 2 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(cel_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  elif order == "Cappuchino":
    capp_total = 6 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(capp_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  elif order == "Black Coffee":
    coffee_total = 3 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(coffee_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  else:
    total = price * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  
time.sleep(3)
print("\nYour " + quantity + " " + order + " will be ready soon! Please have a seat, and we will call your name when it's ready.\n")
  
time.sleep(10)
print(name + "! Your " + order + " is ready! Please come collect it.\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("Enjoy your beverage, " + name + ("!"))
```

Output: [terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtiiH.png)
This is my first time posting, so it made it a link

Output when I only do 1: [terminal output with only 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wrh5.png)

Let me know how I can solve this. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your code covering orders begins with `if quantity == "1":`. You don't even bother to compute a price when the `quantity` is anything else. What are you expecting it to do? As written, it seems like all the code inside it works just fine for an arbitrary `quantity` (though it's nonsensical for negative values), so just deleting that `if quantity == "1":` test and dedenting the body seems like it should work.

Comment: didn't even think about that. by adding another if statement with quantity > "1": i was able to get it working. thanks for your help

Comment: Why would you need different code for different quantities? Just multiply the price by the quantity.

Comment: I'm using separate ones so it will either have a plural or singular form to measure words. Just to make it a bit more grammatically correct.

Comment: @georgealanzo: None of your code inside the `if` was adjusting (or needed to adjust) grammar for singular vs. plural...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using

```
if quantity == "1": 
  do all the price calculations
```

That's why it is only working when you get just 1 item, quantity is equal to "1". When you use another quantity the if statement just ignores the rest of the code.

To solve this issue you can delete that line.

```
import time

print("Hello! Welcome to George's Coffee.")
name = input("What is your name for the order?\n")
print("\nHello " + name + "! Thank you for coming to George's Coffee!\n")
print("On todays menu, we have the following:\n" + "Lattee\n" + "Hot Chocolate\n" + "Mocha\n" + "Celcius\n" + "Cappuchino\n" + "Black Coffee\n" + "All items are $8 because we need money to fund the hacking of the government.")

price = 8
order = input("\nWhat would you like to order today?\n")
quantity = input("How many " + order + "s would you like?\n")

#singular (=1)
if order == "Lattee":
    latte_total = float(2.95) * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(latte_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
elif order == "Hot Chocolate":
    hot_chocolate_total = 2 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(hot_chocolate_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
elif order == "Mocha":
    mocha_total = 5 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(mocha_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
elif order == "Celcius":
    cel_total = 2 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(cel_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
elif order == "Cappuchino":
    capp_total = 6 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(capp_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
elif order == "Black Coffee":
    coffee_total = 3 * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(coffee_total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
else:
    total = price * int(quantity)
    print("Amazing choice! That will be $" + str(total) + ". Please enter your credit card.")
  
time.sleep(3)
print("\nYour " + quantity + " " + order + " will be ready soon! Please have a seat, and we will call your name when it's ready.\n")
  
time.sleep(10)
print(name + "! Your " + order + " is ready! Please come collect it.\n")
time.sleep(2)
print("Enjoy your beverage, " + name + ("!"))
```